# Unable to create Sqlalchemy query

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, database-schema, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 4 tables

> Events

1. Event_ID
2. Event_Name
3. Seller_ID

> Auctions

1. Auction_ID
2. Event_ID

> Biddings

1. Bidding_ID
2. Auction_ID
3. Buyer_ID
4. Creation_Date

> Orders

1. Order_ID
2. Event_ID
3. Buyer_ID
4. Creation_Date

Now in this schema

- Orders and Auctions are dependent on Event
- Biddings is dependent on Auctions
- Event can have multiple Orders and Auctions, Auction can have multiple Biddings

I want to create a query so that to select all `Events` whose `Orders` has a particular `Buyer_ID` `OR` whose `Auctions` has `Biddings` with particular `Buyer_ID`. Getting this will require several joins. Thats not the problem I think. The problem is I have to sort the final result by `Biddings.Creation_Date` and `Orders.Creation_Date`.

In other words I just want to get the Events for which Buyer got the Order or the Events for which Buyer submitted Bid. The final result should be ordered by the dates on which he did these actions.

I am using pagination. I don't want to fetch all records and sort them later programatically. 
Also, I am willing to modify my schema if changing it can resolve this problem.

Comment: It isn't clear what the actual problem here is. You've kind of described around it, but not stated the actual problem you are trying to solve. You said what you want to get, but what problem are you having with doing that?

Comment: I need to sort the final result by columns that lie in two different tables. How can I do that?

Comment: In plain SQL, just `ORDER BY t1.col1, t2.col2`. Presumably your issue is with SQLAlchemy not PostgreSQL, so hopefully someone who knows SQLAlchemy will come along and see this.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully achieved this through the following query.

> bid_event = (db.session.query(Event,
>   Bidding.created_on.label('created_on')).\
>                                   join(Auction).\
>                                   join(Bidding).\
>                                   filter(Bidding.seller_id == 2)\
>                                   )
>
> order_event = (db.session.query(Event,
>   Order.created_on.label('created_on')).\
>                                   join(Order).\
>                                   filter(Order.seller_id == 2)\
>                                   )
>
> records = bid_event.union(order_event).order_by('created_on').all()

There is still small problem with this. It returns duplicate records. I want to get distinct records by

> Event_ID

Someone suggested to use `group_by` but I am unable to use it in sqlalchemy with union clause.